# WholeFileInputFormat along with CombineFileInputFormat

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, bigdata, hadoop-yarn

How WholeFileInputFormat can be used with CombineFileInputFormat? Assume, I have 10,000 small binary files and currently using WholeFileInputFormat. It's working fine but not efficient as it's creating 10,000 number of mappers. Again each map task takes only few seconds. That's why I want to pass more files to a single mapper to reduce overhead. One option is to use CombineFileInputFormat. I was able to run it and it's creating expected number of mappers but its running for infinite time. I think my implementation for **getProgress** is wrong and noticed that each of the map job is only reading the 1st file of the split, not moving to next files in the list.

Here is my custom input format:

```
public class MyCombineFileInputFormat extends CombineFileInputFormat<NullWritable, BytesWritable> {

public MyCombineFileInputFormat() {
    super();
    setMaxSplitSize(1048576);
}


protected boolean isSplitable(JobContext context, Path file) {
    return false;
}


@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
@Override
public RecordReader<NullWritable, BytesWritable> getRecordReader(InputSplit split, JobConf job,
        Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
    return new CombineFileRecordReader<NullWritable, BytesWritable>(job, (CombineFileSplit) split, reporter,
        (Class) MyCombineFileRecordReader.class);
}
```

}

Here is my custom combine file reader:

```
public class MyCombineFileRecordReader implements RecordReader<NullWritable, BytesWritable> {

private NullWritable key = NullWritable.get();

private BytesWritable value = new BytesWritable();
private Path path;
private FileSystem fs;
private FileSplit filesplit;
private int totalNumOfPaths;
private static int processedPaths;

public static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(MyCombineFileRecordReader.class);


public MyCombineFileRecordReader(CombineFileSplit split, Configuration conf, Reporter reporter, Integer index)
        throws IOException {
    this.totalNumOfPaths = split.getNumPaths();
    LOGGER.info("**** Total number of paths: " + totalNumOfPaths);
    this.filesplit =
            new FileSplit(split.getPath(index), split.getOffset(index), split.getLength(index),
                split.getLocations());
    this.path = split.getPath(index);
    this.fs = this.path.getFileSystem(conf);
    processedPaths = 0;
}

--- I think this is not right
@Override
public float getProgress() throws IOException {
    if (processedPaths == totalNumOfPaths) {
        LOGGER.info("**** Completed # of files");
        return 1.0f;
    } else {
        return 0.0f;
    }
}

--- I have found that this method is being called multiple times for the same file 
@Override
public boolean next(NullWritable key, BytesWritable val) throws IOException {
    if (filesplit != null) {
        byte[] contents = new byte[(int) filesplit.getLength()];
        LOGGER.info("**** Reading path: " + path);
        FSDataInputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = fs.open(path);
            IOUtils.readFully(in, contents, 0, contents.length);
            value.set(contents, 0, contents.length);
            LOGGER.info("**** Processed path count: " + processedPaths);
            processedPaths++;
        } finally {
            IOUtils.closeStream(in);
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}


@Override
public NullWritable createKey() {
    return key;
}
@Override
public BytesWritable createValue() {
    return value;
}
```

}

Comment: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/bd-hadoopcombine/ .. this has an implementation of what you have done. See if it helps.

Comment: I guess this is similar to what you are looking for. Have a look at this RecordReader implementation. http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/mahout/trunk/integration/src/main/java/org/apache/mahout/text/WholeFileRecordReader.java

Comment: @FallingCoconut That did the trick! Now it's working. It looks like the constructor of the reader is being called multiple times based on total number of index in the split. After checking that link and the source code, it cleared out my confusion. Thanks a lot!